# PHP/HTML : How to correctly format a table with SQL data and dropdown box ?

Tags: php, html, mysql, layout, formatting

I am having a little bit of trouble trying to format a table to the way I want it. It is supposed to display a list of all movie ids in one column and then a dropdown in the next allowing the user to change the pay status.

The desired result is as such :

-- Movie Id  -----------Pay Status-------

[___id 1____]      [____dropdown_____]

[___id 2____]

[___id 3____]

However I am currently getting something like this :

-- Movie Id  -----------Pay Status-------

[___id 1____]

[___id 2____]

[___id 3____]

[____dropdown_____]

The code i am working on is below :

```
         echo "<tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Pay Status</th>
        </tr>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr><td>" . $row ["movieid"] . "</tr>";
    }

    //// pay status


    echo "<td>" . "<select name='payid'>";
    while ($row = $result5->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['payid'] . "'>" . $row['payid'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>" . "</td>";
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have to open the <tr> tag in outside of the first while loop and closing the tr tag </tr> at end. Then it will solve your problem.